# Unable to send and receive ajax data in Struts 2

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, struts2

I am trying to send data using `ajax` and retrieving the same in `ajax`

Here is my `ajax` code

```
    $.ajax({
           url:"getSampleData",
           type:'GET',
        data : {'var':cellValue},
         statusCode:{
                 404:function(data){
                     returnValue = data; 
                    alert("This is 404 "+data.value);
                },
                403: function(data){
                returnValue = data;
            }
        }
    }
);
```

And In my `struts.xml` I am catching like this.

```
    <action  name="getSampleData" 
             class="ActionClass" 
             method="sampleMethod">
         <result name="success" type="httpheader" >
          <param name="statusCode" >404</param>
         </result>           
         <result name="fail" type="httpheader">
          <param name="statusCode" >403</param>
         </result>
    </action>
```

In My action class

```
    //Getters and setters for `var` 

    public String sampleMethod()
       {
           sysout("This is sample data "+getVar());//Here I am getting null value
        }
```

Here My problem is I can get that `cellValue` before I call ajax action but in my action class I am getting null value and as response I am making an alert call But I am unable to get that alert message.

Help would be appreciated , Thank You

Comment: what exactly is `cellValue`? and any specific reasons for using [`404`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404) for success?

Comment: Okay That `cellValue` will be some integer value .. For Using `404` no specific reason I just want to know the response from server

Comment: make sure `var` is of `String` type in ActionClass as Data to be sent to the server. It is converted to a query string, if not already a string. [See here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: I am sure of that I am treating that as `String` only.. ..

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you are getting null @ action method, check the property var is null or not.

In response you have to use

```
  <param name="status" >403</param>
```

insted of

```
  `<param name="statusCode" >403</param>`
```

please refer the link for more information [HTTP Header Response](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.1.x/docs/httpheader-result.html)

Comment: Somehow its correct, but from your code it does not return any data, that could be printed out!